# Docker with different gateways on containers

Tags: ubuntu, networking, docker, ifconfig

Firstly, sorry for my bad english.

We have a ubuntu server which has 2 eth interface and 2 different ip. We want to host 2 apps with 2 docker containers and in containers we must use self-domain (domains which we redirect to ips) ip's as gateway.

In other words, when we attach container 1 (hosts for xx.xx.xx.98 and its domain) and run "curl http://checkip.dyndns.org" we want to see xx.xx.xx.98 ip in dyndns.org response. And in container 2 (hosts for xx.xx.xx.99 and its domain) we want to see xx.xx.xx.99 ip in dyndns.org response.

Is it possible and if it is, how can we do this?

In addition, I read these articles and I find out that we can use only one bridge for docker, this means all docker containers have to use same gateway. Is it true?

https://docs.docker.com/articles/networking/#bridge-building
http://jpetazzo.github.io/2013/10/16/configure-docker-bridge-network/

Answer (score 1):

You can have as many bridges as you like, so long as you do all the configuration yourself.  So you can follow the instructions in [bridge-building](https://docs.docker.com/articles/networking/#bridge-building) twice to create two bridges, then follow [the other part](https://docs.docker.com/articles/networking/#how-docker-networks-a-container) to attach one container to one bridge and the other container to the other bridge.

Start each container with `--net=none` to make sure Docker leaves it unconfigured so you can do it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something similar too `-p 127.0.0.1:5000:5000` in yor docker run command to bind port to a specific interface. Then you can set that interface's default gateway as needed on the host. [Here](http://www.thomas-krenn.com/en/wiki/Two_Default_Gateways_on_One_System) is a tutorial that walks through setting up a gateway per interface using the iproute2 utility. Although I don't think you need to do anything with gateways to do what you need as long as the interfaces are setup correctly.